# Checking if a domain name is registered

Tags: php, python, dns, names

How would I go about checking if a domain name is registered? I was thinking about checking if it has a corresponding IP but it doesn't seem to work as well as I had hoped. Is there a solution in either PHP or Python that can check?

Comment: I just got to know there is a python module named [pywhois](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/pywhois). To install it, `pip install python-whois`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Registered" doesn't mean "assigned an IP address". To know whether a domain name is registered, you'll need to do a whois query.

For Python, there's [pywhois](http://code.google.com/p/pywhois/), but from its web site it seems somewhat immature. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394/what-python-way-would-you-suggest-to-check-whois-database-records).

For PHP, there's... surprise... [phpwhois](http://www.phpwhois.org/).

Comment: Yeah, the whole registered not meaning assigned an ip address is why it failed as a solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

Mike Nott has created a [simple PHP class](http://www.nott.org/blog/php-whois-script.html) that allows you to query the who.is data for any domain you wish.

Once you call

```
    $whois = getwhois($sld, $tld);
```

you then just need to check the contents of `$whois` to determine whether the domain is currently registered.

Answer (score 0):

use [the net_whois package from pear](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Whois).
for multiple results, which may occur when server names are also reported along with domain names do something similar to:

```
require_once ¨Net/Whois.php¨;
$whois = new Net_Whois;
$whois->authorative = true;
$data = $whois->query(¨example.com¨);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a domain name is registered you need two informations:

- The whois server for the respective top level domain (or second level domain)
- A matching pattern for the response of that whois server

Those informations do change frequently. This [Whois Server list](https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-server-list) tries to compile the needed informations for more than 500 top level domains. The list also offers an [API service](http://whois-api.domaininformation.de/) to check if a domain is available. The PHP client for that API would be [whois-api-php](https://github.com/whois-server-list/whois-api-php):

```
$whoisApi = new whoisServerList\WhoisApi("apiKey");
echo $whoisApi->isAvailable("example.net") ? "available" : "registered";
```