# check to see if a domain is available or not using PHP?

Tags: php

If I have a domain like `www.example.com` and I want to check if it is available using DNS records (not whois)...

Is it possible to do this using PHP?

Comment: it seems it is in standard php library, check this function
<http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php>

Comment: If by "available", you mean available for purchase or registration, you cannot determine this reliably using DNS. For example, `moose9moose2.ph` is available, but has an A record. While `ph.moose9moose2` has no DNS records, but is not available for registration. You can try to add rules to cover all the possible cases, but you'll likely never finish.

Comment: @David, Correct, but if dns isn't enough, what would you recommend instead?

Comment: See the question you duplicated: Whois.

Comment: It's getting hard to tell what your question is. Is your question "how can I tell if a domain is available in PHP", "how can I tell if a domain is registered in PHP", or "how can I do DNS in PHP"? Why don't you just tell us what you're actually trying to do and ask us how best to do it? Your question is becoming like "I want to help my grandmother buy a house, but I want to do it with a jackhammer. How can I do that best?"

Comment: Question is: "how can I tell if a domain is available using PHP (using DNS and not whois)?"  That is the question.

Comment: Re-opening, the questions are sufficiently different.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use checkdnsrr or gethostbyname:

Documentation:

http://www.php.net/checkdnsrr

http://www.php.net/gethostbyname

Example checkdnsrr:

```
<?php
 if ( checkdnsrr('example.com.', 'ANY') ) {
  echo "DNS Record found";
 }
 else {
  echo "NO DNS Record found";
 }
?>
```

Example gethostbyname:

```
<?php
 $domain = 'example.com';
 if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
  echo "DNS Record found";
 }
 else {
  echo "NO DNS Record found";
 }
?>
```

Comment: This shows as found for everything...example -  if ( checkdnsrr('examjhkasdjkhbasdle.com', 'ANY') ) {
  echo "DNS Record found";
 }
 else {
  echo "NO DNS Record found";
 }

Comment: here is the second example using gethostbyname: <?php
 $domain = 'asdasdxample.com';
 if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
  echo "DNS Record found";
 }
 else {
  echo "NO DNS Record found";
 }
?>

Comment: Solution: for checkdnsrr to work, you must add a period after the domain name, example: checkdnsrr('example.com.',"ANY")

Comment: sorry, i have edited my answer to include the missing dot and also to include my previous comment with the gethostbyname example :)

Comment: if domain is in pending delete status, neither of these works. better to use a registrar api or parse whois information i think.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this script to return multiple domains at once? For example: I want to check foo.com, example.com, website.com with one query.

Comment: yeah, none of these work really. 1. the domain may not have an SOA record in the registry, 2. it could be on a block list either of these cases would fail any kind of DNS lookup, but the domain is still not available.

Comment: You can use gethostbyname() function also here is demo https://speedysense.com/php-domain-availablity-checker-script/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "available." If you mean available for registration, it is not possible to determine based on DNS information alone. The whois system must be used. An easy way to test is to take an unused domain name and set the nameservers to something invalid. DNS will not be available, but the domain is still unavailable for registration. I just tested the suggestions of checkdnsrr(), gethostbyname(), and dns_get_record(). All show that no DNS is returned for a domain that cannot be registered.

The following question offers some more details:
[Checking if a domain name is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697663/checking-if-a-domain-name-is-registered)

Answer (score 1):

All answers suggest using some PHP library. There's a function in *vanilla* PHP (version 5 to 7) that fetches DNS records for a specific domain.

Utilising the following **PHP** line,

```php
sizeof(dns_get_record("example.com"))
```

you will get an INT corresponding to the number of DNS records. Therefore, consider something alike:

```
if (sizeof(dns_get_record("example.com")) > 0) echo "Domain has DNS records";
else echo "Domain does not have any DNS records";
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the API that will do the job.

http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/domain-availability.php

http://www.dynadot.com/domain/api.html

http://www.opensrs.com/site/integration/api

Answer (score 0):

I should go for this package [Domain-Availability](https://github.com/HelgeSverre/Domain-Availability) it's support a lot of Top Level Domains and is written in a Object Oriented way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script to check domain availability for some domains using whois.
In this example we check all number domains between 10 and 999 for a given top level domain (spoiler alert: they're mostly taken).

Here are predefined examples for .com .pe .ee .cc and .gg. It runs a whois search for the domain and then looks for the words "no match for domain" in the output.

```
$tld = "com" ;

$lookFor = array();
$lookFor['com'] = "No match for domain" ; // .com
$lookFor['pe'] = "No Object Found" ; // .pe
$lookFor['ee'] = "Domain not found" ; // ee
$lookFor['cc'] = "No match for" ; // cc
$lookFor['gg'] = "NOT FOUND" ;

$i = 10 ;
while($i < 10000)
{
    $domain = "$i.$tld" ;
    $dig = `whois $domain` ;

    
    if(stripos($dig, $lookFor[$tld]) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo "$domain is available\n" ;
    } else {
        echo "$domain bad\n" ;          
    }
     
     $i ++ ;
     
}
```