# What is the simplest way to execute WHOIS protocol with python?

Tags: python, networking, ip, whois, pywhois

Im looking for a library or a code module that is most reccomended for WHOIS protocol.

Note that i've been allready googling it , but i didnt found what i was looking for.

what i need is something like this :

```
WHOIS(ip)
```

and the output will be the whois information about this IP (and not url!) , and None if there isn't such.

thanks :)

Comment: [WhoIs protocol example with Twisted](https://github.com/darkrho/Random-Code/blob/master/python/twisted/whoisclient.py)

Comment: try http://philipjm.free.fr/python/whois/doc/ from http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=whois+ip+python+module

Answer (score 3):

There is a [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577364-whois-client/) for doing whois.

Also this question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394/what-python-way-would-you-suggest-to-check-whois-database-records)